# How to detect time-periods present in a signal using FFT?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, signal-processing, fft

I'm trying to determine the periodicities present in a given waveform.

This is my signal, which is a sinusoidal waveform:

```
t_week = np.linspace(1,480, 480)
t_weekend=np.linspace(1,192,192)
T=96 #Time Period
x_weekday = 10*np.sin(2*np.pi*t_week/T)+10
x_weekend = 2*np.sin(2*np.pi*t_weekend/T)+10
x_daily_weekly_sinu = np.concatenate((x_weekday, x_weekend)) 

#Creating the Signal
x_daily_weekly_long_sinu = np.concatenate((x_daily_weekly_sinu,x_daily_weekly_sinu,x_daily_weekly_sinu,x_daily_weekly_sinu,x_daily_weekly_sinu,x_daily_weekly_sinu,x_daily_weekly_sinu,x_daily_weekly_sinu,x_daily_weekly_sinu,x_daily_weekly_sinu))

#Visualization
plt.plot(x_daily_weekly_long_sinu)
plt.show()
```

[image]

In order to determine the two periods present, which are 96 & 672, I'm creating the FFT of the waveform as follows:

```
f, Pxx = signal.periodogram(x_daily_weekly_long_sinu, fs = 96, window='hanning', scaling='spectrum')

#Visualization
plt.figure(figsize = (10, 8))
plt.plot(f, Pxx)
plt.xlim(0, 10)
plt.yscale('log')
plt.xlabel('Frequency (cycles/day)')
plt.ylabel('Spectrum Amplitude')
```

The following is the plot of frequencies that I get.

**Can anyone tell why is it showing so many frequencies instead of just two distinct frequencies of 96 & 672?**

[image]

I then try to extract the top frequencies from the FFT:

```
for amp_arg in np.argsort(np.abs(Pxx))[::-1][1:6]:
    day = 1 / f[amp_arg]
    print(day)
```

But my output gives the following values as the top frequencies instead of 96 & 672:

```
1.0144927536231885
0.9859154929577465
1.1666666666666667
0.875
1.4
```

**Why is this happening? Can anyone please help me to determine the correct periods?**

It would be great if I just get a final list of values representing the exact set of periods only.

Comment: my guess: because you have a step from the last value to the first value (signal is not periodic). a step "bumps" all frequencies. look up "window functions" (Hann, Hamming, ...). -- and your signal "modulation" is rectangular, not sinusoidal. rectangles have a lot of harmonics.

Comment: The signal is periodic right? As seen in the plot, there are 2 types of periodicities present. Also, even if the signal is rectangular, it can still be represented as a sum of sines - which's what FFT is based on right?

Comment: the sum of sines is precisely what I mean when I say "harmonics". you see those sines.

Comment: Alright, but is using FFT the correct approach to determine the actual periodicities that are present in this kind of waveform which are 96 & 672? That's my final objective.

Comment: not unreasonable. you could also try autocorrelation but I can't say what benefits and downsides that has vs. FFT/DFT.

Comment: So if FFT is a reasonable technique, then is there any modification that I can do in my approach/code such that I can exactly determine 96 & 672 as my time periods?

Comment: "periodogram" looks strange. try a regular dft/fft.

Comment: Oh, I was of the assumption that both Periodogram & FFT are the same thing. Will need to understand the difference better.

Comment: wikipedia says that thing is "the fourier transform of the autocorrelation function".... so that's definitely more than _just_ a fourier of the signal.